# How to use Collapse Sidebar in blazor webassembly

Tags: javascript, html, css, blazor

I want to make a collapse sidebar in blzor webassembly. I found a sample of collapse sidebar in w3schools.com ([enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp)) but i have no idea how can i perform it in blazor.

Is it possible to make a collapse sidebar like the sample of w3schools in blazor webassembly. I will be thankful if somebody help.

Comment: https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/sidebar/

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy actually it is just changing a two widths:

You will still need the css.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div style="@sidebarWidth" class="sidebar">
    <a class="closebtn" @onclick="CloseNav">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="@mainMargin">
    @if (width == 0)
    {
    <button class="openbtn" @onclick="OpenNav">&#9776; Open Sidebar</button>
    } else {
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
    }
    <p>@Body</p>
</div>

@code {
    int width = 0;
    string sidebarWidth => $"width: {width}px;";
    string mainMargin => $"margin-left: {width}px;";
    void OpenNav() => width = 250;
    void CloseNav() => width = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i just wnat to know one more thing
when i click open sidebar the main navmenu(MainMenu of blazor) Does not move to the right, is it possible when i click on open sidebar also have the Main navmenu?

Comment: @Arvin I just created a new Blazor .net 5.0 project. I used the above to replace MainLayout.razor contents and then replaced MainLayout.razor.css contents with the css from the link. It opened and closed as expected.